# find the specified element from sibling xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I specify the element right next to '>' by xpath by not using text? In my case, I only want element of "n" I have build

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/*[contains(text(),">")]/preceding-sibling::a')
```

but I get all of the sibling nodes of element ">" like 1 ,2 ,3, n

```
<div >
    <div >
    <a > 1 < /a >
    <a > 2 < /a >
    <a > 3 < /a >
    <a > n < /a >
    <a > > < / a >
    < / div >
< / div >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant try below `XPath` to select *the first* preceding sibling of link with text `" > "`:

```
//a[normalize-space()=">"]/preceding-sibling::a[position()=1]
```

Comment: i cannot really use position neither because it is for click pagination element, since pagination size keep changing, I do not really know what position may be

Comment: Clarify your issue. Which exact element you need to locate?

Comment: i need to locate element **<a> n </a>** by xpath of **<a> > </a>**

Comment: So why you can't use my solution? It allow to select link just before `>` link.

Comment: my bad, it works. but what is different than **normalize-space()=">"** and ***[contains(text(), "<")]**?